# How to modify attributes on polymer elements with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, polymer, material-design

Pretty basic question, not even sure if it's polymer specific since I think i'm just lacking some basic javascript knowledge.

Anyways what I am trying to do is write a conditional statement based on the slider values entered in by the user.

If the user were to enter an amount less than 5 on the slider then a contact form would pop up
else if the sliders value is greater than 5 a list will appear.

This is what I have so far

HTML

```
  <paper-slider id="slider" min="{{quiz.min}}" max="{{quiz.max}}" step="{{quiz.step || 1}}" immediateValue="{{value}}"></paper-slider>
```

JS

```
<script>

  Polymer('topeka-quiz-picker', {

    eventDelegates: {
      down: 'answered',
    },

    quizChanged: function() {
      this.value = this.$.slider.value = this.$.slider.secondaryProgress = this.quiz.min || 0;
    }



  });

  if(this.value > 5) {

    /* shows contact form */
  } else {
    /* shows list */ 
  }

</script>
```

Edit* 
What would I have to put to track the value entered by the user and how would I create an element in the else statement or go to a different card?

This is the topeka site I am trying to modify 
https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use [custom filters](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/expressions.html#custom-filters)

Here is one example: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LPudwJNaaplLQ065aGtM?p=preview)

```
 <paper-slider immediateValue="{{ val }}"></paper-slider>
 {{ val  | check }}
 ...
 check: function(value) {

    if (value < 100) {
        return 'Value < 100';
    }
    return value;
  },
```